# Java reflection getTypeParameters().length returns 0

Tags: java, reflection

I have a simple class

```
public class Pet {
    private String petName;
    private int petAge;

    public Pet() {
    }

    public Pet(String petName, int petAge) {
        this.petName = petName;
        this.petAge = petAge;
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to find arguments, I get two zeros. I still can't find out why. Any suggestion?

```
        Constructor[] constructors = Pet.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
        for (Constructor c : constructors) {
            System.out.println(c.getTypeParameters().length);
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong method.

To the get number of arguments of each constructor, use:

```
System.out.println("ctor len " + c.getParameterCount());
```

You'll get `0` and `2`, as expected.

`getTypeParameters().length` returns the number of generic type parameters, and none of your constructors have generic type parameters.

If, for example, you change your second constructor to:

```
public <Y> Pet(String petName, int petAge) {
    ....
}
```

`getTypeParameters().length` will be `1` for that constructor.

See the Javadoc:

> **int java.lang.reflect.Constructor.getParameterCount()**
>
> Returns the number of formal parameters (whether explicitly declared or implicitly declared or neither) for the executable represented by this object.
>
> **TypeVariable[] java.lang.reflect.Constructor.getTypeParameters()**
>
> Returns an array of TypeVariable objects that represent the type variables declared by the generic declaration represented by this GenericDeclaration object, in declaration order. Returns an array of length 0 if the underlying generic declaration declares no type variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
c.getParameterCount()
```

will return `0` and `2` as per your current code for `non-typed constructor`.